# Display color next to treeview item in pyqt

Tags: c++, pyqt

I have a simple tree view in qt using c++. Each item in my treeview has a property of color which the user can change. How can I display a color swatch or colored rectangle beside each item in the treeview as seen in the image below.

I can post code for image if necessary. Thank you guys. I'm a bit stuck.

[image]

Comment: How are you using widget or standard/abstract item model? Code or brief description of code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the `data` method of your `QAbstractItemModel` descendant, return a `QColor` object if `role == Qt::DecorationRole`.

By the way, the C++ tag doesn't match with the PyQt tag. Or do you mean the Qt tag?

Comment: But how can I actually display the color next to the item in the tree view. I only know a way to display an icon which I don't want to do since the color can change dynamically.

Comment: You didn't try my suggestion, did you? If you return a color for the QDecorationRole, it is drawn as a square in that color next to the item. Do you actually use a `QTreeView` that is connected to a model, or do you use a `QTreeWidget`?